# Missing variable in ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

I am doing a one-way ANOVA in R, which I have done successfully in the past. However this time it continually cuts out the final variable.
My data is five columns in a CSV with numbers from 1-366. 
A sample looks like this:

```
w   x   y   z   all_data
181 314 207 207 207
176 315 207 207 207
176 315 209 209 209
176 315 209 209 209
177 316 209 209 209
177 149 209 209 209
177 149 209 209 209
278 154 209 209 209
278 154 209 209 209
278 154 209 209 209
278 154 209 209 209
```

When I perform the ANOVA, this is my result.

```
> xdata <- read.csv("xdata.csv")
> wdatalm <- lm(all_data ~ w + x + y + z, data = xdata)
> anova(wdatalm)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: all_data
                  Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq    F value    Pr(>F)    
w                  1 1650752 1650752 5.2276e+31 < 2.2e-16 ***
x                  1 2947290 2947290 9.3335e+31 < 2.2e-16 ***
y                  1 9956250 9956250 3.1529e+32 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals       7969       0       0                         
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Warning message:
In anova.lm(nocollm) :
  ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable
```

I tried it again in a different order and got a different result that was still missing the final variable.

```
> zdatalm <- lm(all_data ~ z + w + x + y, data = xdata)
> anova(zdatalm)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: all_data
             Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq    F value Pr(>F)    
z             1 14554292 14554292 2.6457e+31 <2e-16 ***
w             1        0        0 1.0400e-02 0.9188    
x             1        0        0 0.0000e+00 0.9961    
Residuals  7969        0        0                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Warning message:
In anova.lm(nocollm) :
  ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable
```

Regarding the error message, I do know that my data is possibly too close a fit but it doesn't seem that this should cause the test to cut out a variable. Are there any ways I can prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 3):

It's because column `y` and `z` are perfectly collinear with each other in your dataset (and also with your dependant variable btw), which is why one of them will be always dropped, depending on the order in your formula.

```
> cor(xdata)
#                  w          x          y          z   all_data
#w         1.0000000 -0.6730963  0.3430370  0.3430370  0.3430370
#x        -0.6730963  1.0000000 -0.5133621 -0.5133621 -0.5133621
#y         0.3430370 -0.5133621  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000
#z         0.3430370 -0.5133621  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000
#all_data  0.3430370 -0.5133621  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000
```

Otherwise the coefficient estimates of your multiple regression may change dramatically in response to small changes in the model or the data. Consequently, your model may not give valid results about any individual predictor, or about which predictors are redundant with respect to others.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the removal of one of your variables is not that the fit is perfect, but that two variables are perfect copies (i.e. they are highly colinear):

```
ano <-anova(wdatalm)
aov(wdatalm)
> ...
> 1 out of 5 effects not estimable
> ...
```

when you replace the "perfect" predictors with random but also highly colinear variables, you still miss one of them in the result:

```
xdata$y <- xdata$z <- rnorm(nrow(xdata))
wdatalm <- lm(all_data ~ w + x + y + z, data = xdata)
anova(wdatalm)
```

.. no more warning about near-perfect fits, but:

```
aov(wdatalm)
> ...
> 1 out of 5 effects not estimable
> ...
```